# ¿Cómo hacer que filter de dplyr me filtre mi condición sin omitir alguna fila?

Tags: rstudio, r-dplyr, dplyr

Estoy trabajando en R con un data.frame de más de 86000 observaciones y 5 variables (las importantes son razon y nombre), en la cual tengo nombre de templos religiosos.
Estoy usando filter para filtrar todas las filas que contengan la palabra "CAPILLA" "PARROQUIA", "DICOESIS", etc, y guardarlas en un nuevo objeto, el código parece funcionar porque me da observaciones pero son muy pocas, revisando la base de datos hay observaciones que no está filtrando.
Ya intente con

`A <- baserel %>% filter(razon == "PARROQUIA" | razon == "CAPILLA" | razon == "VICARIA" | razon == "PRELATURA" | razon == "DIOCESIS" |  razon == "ARQUIDIOCESIS" | razon == "EXARQUIA")`

Y da observaciones pero muy pocas.
Intente

`AA <- baserel %>% filter(nombre != c("PARROQUIA", "CAPILLA", "VICARIA", "PRELATURA",  "DIOCESIS", "ARQUIDIOCESIS", "EXARQUIA", "CATOLICO"))`

`AAA <- baserel %>% filter(razon %in% "CAPILLA")`
Aquí me arroja 9 observaciones y buscando en la base coincidencias con esas palabra arroja más de 13000 observaciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problemas es que está ejecutando sin problemas pero no me esta dando todas las observaciones que hay. ¿cómo le hago para que al filtrar me de todas las coincidencias con las palabras que me interesan?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que estas usando el operador de igualdad `==` por lo que si buscas `CAPILLA` jamás va a recuperar cadenas del tipo `La CAPILLA del SEÑOR` por que ciertamente las cadenas no son iguales. La búsqueda a utilizar, es la de contenido:

```
baserel %>% 
  filter(grepl("CAPILLA", razon))
```

`grepl()` retornará `TRUE` o `FALSE` si `razon` "contiene" la palabra `CAPILLA`. Puedes aprovechar las expresiones regulares para construir un `OR` entre varias cadenas:

```
 baserel %>% 
      filter(grepl("PARROQUIA|CAPILLA|VICARIA|PRELATURA|DIOCESIS|ARQUIDIOCESIS", razon))
```